# Using RecyclerView in android studio but nothing is getting printed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

This is the page where i want to print all the usernames and price extracted from Parse dashboard

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        final RecyclerView list=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        final ArrayList<String> username = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayList<String> netPrice = new ArrayList<String>();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Image");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e==null){
                    if (objects.size()>0) {
                        for(ParseObject object : objects){
                            String user=object.getString("username");
                            String price=object.getString("price");
                            username.add(user);
                            netPrice.add(price);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else{
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        list.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(username,netPrice));
    }

   
}
```

This is my Adapter named ListAdapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private ArrayList<String>data1;
    private ArrayList<String>data2;

    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<String> data1, ArrayList<String> data2){
        this.data1=data1;
        this.data2=data2;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,parent,false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
          String title1=data1.get(position);
        final TextView viewById1 = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        viewById1.setText(title1);
        String title2=data2.get(position);
        final TextView viewById2 = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        viewById2.setText(title2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data1.size();
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
 }
```

This shows no error but nothing is getting printed.
I have passed ArrayList in my Adapter, am I allowed to that?
please help, I am struck badly trying to do this since 8 hrs.

Comment: `list.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(user,netPrice));` seems like you're always just setting the item in the adapter equal to one user, and your `getItemCount` is also just returning 1

Comment: it's important to understand that a recyclerview only has one adapter, but that adapter handles ALL data, you don't create a new adapter per item in the list. go review some basic recycler examples, i'm sure you'll find what you need :)

Comment: You are doing wrong code. Please read about recyclerview https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example

Comment: @a_local_nobody , I have made some changes , please review my question and help. Now it isn't showing anything

Answer (score 1):

your item count should have the size of the items you want to show

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 1; // return here the number of items
}
```

Comment: this won't fix the problem, OP is setting a new adapter for every user instead of having one adapter with a list of users

Comment: first thing i did was look at the adapter :) but you are right, my answer is just a part of the problem.

Comment: "bugs are hardly ever found in the obvious places, because if they were, we wouldn't have so many bugs" - a_local_nobody :D jokes aside, OP is treating every instance of the recycler as a new entry, which is why they have set count to 1 and they are creating a new adapter for every record

Answer (score 0):

problem is with the background word.

It is calling `query.findInBackground` and directly after that `list.setAdapter(...)` which at this time, [username, netPrice] are still empty lists.
So you need to wait, until you `done` method is done and then set data in recycleView.

You can do that by:

1 - Create a method `setRecyclerViewData` which will set the recyclerview data.

2 - call `setRecyclerViewData` inside `done` after it finishes the for each loop
that way you will be sure that [username, netPrice] have some data.

```java
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e==null){
            if (objects.size()>0) {
                for(ParseObject object : objects){
                    String user=object.getString("username");
                    String price=object.getString("price");
                    username.add(user);
                    netPrice.add(price);
                  }
                  setRecyclerView(username, netPrice);
             }
             else{
                 log.d("Tag", "Objects size = 0");
             }
         }
         else{
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
});
```

```java
private void setRecyclerView(ArrayList<String> username, ArrayList<String> netPrice){
    list.setAdapter(newListAdapter(username,netPrice));
}
```

plus thing don't usually go this way in recylerview adapter, it is not showing error OK, but this is not the convention.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing an empty screen is because your adapter contains no data, after getting the data in `query.findInBackground`, you don't notify the adapter that there is a new data.

So, what you need to do is

First, store your adapter instance into a variable

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        final ArrayList<String> username = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayList<String> netPrice = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(username,netPrice); // Add this line
        ...
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

Then, in your `query.findInBackground` notify the adapter that there is a new data

```
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e==null){
                    if (objects.size()>0) {
                        for(ParseObject object : objects){
                            String user=object.getString("username");
                            String price=object.getString("price");
                            username.add(user);
                            netPrice.add(price);
                        }
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Add this line
                    }

                }
                else{
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```